# MonetDB multi-tenancy?

Tags: multi-tenant, monetdb

I am evaluating MonetDB for a multi-tenanted OLAP solution. I understand that there is a concept of schema similar to mysql in MonetDb but is it really scalable in terms of schema's. Can I put a reasonable number of schemas and all performing nearly the same or multiple instances of the monetdb server will be needed ?

Also is it scalable in terms of number of indexes? Coz in a multi-tenanted environment our number of indexes will also increase with number of tenants.

I have looked all over to find out about this but could not get a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage multiple instances of the MonetDB server using monetdbd, the MonetDB daemon. I would recommend this for multi-tenant environments. Not sure what you mean by "number of indexes"...

Comment: Lets say I have a 30GB RAM/8 Cores on Amazon instance and average number of rows in one table is 1 million rows, with 40 columns, and indexes on 5 columns. How many instances can I run? (If its less than 10 then I will not bother with MonetDB else I will go through benchmark tests).

Comment: You can run as many as you have disk space for. MonetDB uses memory-mapped files and is thus not limited by the amount of memory on the box. However, whether it is fast remains to be seen in benchmarks. Suggest you try.